# how to apply filter on JQuery DataTable each columns?

Tags: datatables, asp.net-ajax

I want to apply **filter on JQuery-Datatables every columns**.....I have applied data tables in my Report.
But i am unable to apply filters on each columns header on the basis of columns values in data tables. Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: How does your datatable look like? How did you apply the filters? Would this help? https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: Thanks a lot TomTom.